# How to catch formatting error before attempting to set focus

Tags: ms-access

I have code in my Form's Property Sheet [On Key Down] event which sets the focus to the first field in a subform if the user presses tab in the last field of header data.

It works fine as long as the user makes no mistakes in entering data in the last header field.  That field is a date and if the user enters a badly formatted date and presses tab, they get a run-time error 2110 "Access can't move the focus to the control xxx"

Then, if they press end, it will let them go back and adjust the date but it seems to hang on to the initial bad value and repeatedly say "The value you entered isn't appropriate for the input mask." even if it is now a good value.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just set the Subform as the next control in your tabbed order instead of creating your own method for setting focus to the Subform. In the Subform just make sure that the field in question is set to the be the first in the tab order of the Subform.

I think this is kind of one of those "Why reinvent the wheel?" type of scenarios. For more information about setting tab order you can read through: https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Set-the-tab-order-for-controls-ec2943d9-8b07-4778-8157-c1785a0dd438

Example:

Parent Form tab order can be set to: `Parent.ctrl1, Parent.ctrl2, Parent.ctrl3, Parent.subform1`

Then the Subform tab order can be set to: `Subform.ctrl1, Subform.ctrl2, Subform.ctrl3... etc`

In this scenario when you tab to Parent.subform1 you will then change to the tab order of the subform and go to `Subform.ctrl1`

Comment: I don't believe this to be correct.  I am aware that there are tab stops to determine how you move between controls and even records.  But I think the tab stops of forms are independent of each other.  The main form has its own set of tab set of stops (0 thru n) and the subforms have their own set of tabs (0 thru n).  The link you have talks about tabbing from record to record or tab to tab but not form to form.

Comment: @CathyS I'm not positive what version you are running. Though I just double checked and I definitely have the ability to set subforms in my tab order.  Though you do need to make sure the property of the subform has `Tab stop` set to `Yes`.  I don't believe you can then go back from the subform to the parent form though.    I will write an example into my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not seeing how to set Parent.subform1?

Comment: While in Design view click your subform once, then in "Data Source" you will see the name of the form.  That is what it will be called in the tab order of your parent form.

Comment: I'm using Access 2013.  Are you referring to setting the tab index within the property sheet?